# How to stop PyCharm from closing networked folders

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I've been testing out PyCharm but ran into a crazy little feature and or bug and cannot figure out how to solve it.

I've created a project on a network, and created a project locally and added a network folder to the project both are resulting in the same bizarre behavior.

I can open files, navigate the project tree and everything is fine inside of PyCharm. But once I switch focus to another window and then come back to PyCharm, it will automatically close the entire project tree back to the root and close any files I have had open.

This is certainly making PyCharm completely unusable. I've been searching most of the morning to find out how to stop this but haven't even come across any other similar problems.

To test, I made a sample Python directory on the network, filled it with a few folders to simulate modules and added **init**.py files to them all. Then created a PyCharm project in the folder. It will exhibit this behavior and I can't figure out how to stop it from closing everything.  What's going on?

This is Windows Community PyCharm 2017.2.1 Version. A picture would just be everything open and then everything closed and the tree view, since it closes everything when it regains focus. I'm not sure how I'd best take a picture of that.

Comment: I've never had this issue so I really don't know. Are you using Linux or windows, community or professional pycharm? The only thing that I can think of based off the info you've given is this. There is an interesting feature which hides the project tree. You can double click anywhere in the window to make it visible again. But normally you have to manually hide the project tree for this to happen. Could you provide a picture?

Comment: @Afflicted I added to the question for your comments.

Comment: I've never used the community version. If what I mentioned before didn't help you out I'm not sure I can be of any help. Try filling out a bug report what you're describing doesn't sound like an intended feature. Sounds like an issue and the community edition is still relatively new. Sorry :(

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338609/can-you-stop-pycharm-from-automatically-closing-script-files-when-you-click-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug filed in PyCharm for this issue which is yet to be fixed : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171352

Description of the bug mentions :

> I didn't observe the problem with PyCharm 2016.3.3.
>
> PY-171.3780.115, JRE 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS
>   Windows 10(amd64) v10.0 , screens 2560x1440, 1920x1080, 1080x1920

Apparently the issue is in later releases of PyCharm