# Can you stop PyCharm from automatically closing script files when you click out of the program?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having a problem with PyCharm (Community Edition) in that, when I open a `.py` file in the program, I can happily read and write in the file as usual, however when I click out of PyCharm (to look my emails for example) and then click back into it to carry on with my code, the file automatically closes and the project tree structure collapses (so I have to re-open it every time).

So far I have tried changing the tab limit to a high number, but this doesn't seem to help (and it shouldn't be related, since this happens when I open just one file).

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue before.  I'm assuming you're connected to a network shared folder via UNC path (e.g. `\\foo\bar\`)?

If so, [it is not currently supported](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205801099-UNC-path-for-projects-).  You'll need to map your network folder and give it a Drive letter.  Then load up your project using the mapped drive, and it'll work like a charm.

If that's not the scenario though, please give us more information.

Comment: No currently supported extends at least to version 2019-01.

Comment: Happens to me on my local drive :(
Having watched it for a little while, it seems to happen when PyCharm is 'indexing'.  Once it has indexed, things seem to be back to normal.